# Running LWIP TCP/IP Stack with QEMU

Tags: assembly, tcp, kernel, qemu, lwip

I have a simple UNIX-like kernel here:=
http://www.oxkernel.com/download.html

And we tried adding LWIP TCP/IP Stack to it.
I am trying to run it in QEMU under Linux.

Here is the command line for QEMU:=

emu-system-i386 -fda vmox.img -net nic,model=ne2k_isa -net user -net dump -redir tcp:7777::7777

This runs and gets to the point where the TCP stack says it has a connection
established. However, its actually blocked waiting for response.

I tried running a simple client on that port (7777) and host os, and 
I am able to capture packets.

tcpdump has the following output :=

`tcpdump -nnxr qemu-vlan0.pcap
reading from file qemu-vlan0.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
05:04:20.600573 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.2.15 tell 10.0.2.2, length 28
    0x0000:  0001 0800 0604 0001 5255 0a00 0202 0a00
    0x0010:  0202 0000 0000 0000 0a00 020f
05:04:26.572629 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.2.15 tell 10.0.2.2, length 28
    0x0000:  0001 0800 0604 0001 5255 0a00 0202 0a00
    0x0010:  0202 0000 0000 0000 0a00 020f`

However, we never get out of the connection established wait
(its waiting on a semaphore to complete, which only happens when
there is the correct TCP input).

I believe the ne2000 driver is not getting any data from the network card.

I have iobase as 0xC000 and I registered the driver on every IRQ
except the PIT IRQ. And I still get no data. I even call the
isr from a timer and poll it, and I still get no data.

I tried with ne2k_pci and ne2k_isa devices, and still no data.
The ne2k driver is based on this code :=

https://github.com/dreamcat4/lwip/blob/master/contrib/ports/old/ti_c6711/netif/ne2kif.c

Can someone help me out ?
Thanks

Comment: I believe I'm facing a very similar issue, did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: I didn't figure it out yet. Would you like to help ? I did add a different ne 2000 network card driver and need to test it on qemu. I think the problem maybe an unsupported driver in lwip that's not compatible with qemu. In any case, I have yet to test it out. But the code is on the link above. Thanks