# How to route TCP ports/sockets internal to QEMU?

Tags: sockets, tcp, qemu, freertos, bare-metal

I am attempting to run the [FreeRTOS+TCP demo](https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Kernel/tree/d6c89bb3a078bd51a830d30a22919a952bdc424c/FreeRTOS-Plus/Demo/FreeRTOS_Plus_TCP_Minimal_Windows_Simulator) (release 10.1.1):

The code is written for the Windows Simulator, but I am attempting to target the Xilinx Zynq, emulated by [QEMU](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/ARM) (version 4.2.0).  The host machine is Ubuntu 16.04. There exists a
[Network Interface port](https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Kernel/tree/d6c89bb3a078bd51a830d30a22919a952bdc424c/FreeRTOS-Plus/Source/FreeRTOS-Plus-TCP/portable/NetworkInterface/Zynq) for the **TCP** part of **FreeRTOS+TCP**, so this should be possible.

One of the obvious modifications to the demo is changing the way messages are printed, and removing calls to the Windows `Sleep` function.  Also, I am using [ARM semihosting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60557319/12940429) to view the output of the print statements.

Besides these changes, what changes will I need to make to the command line call?  The demo creates a TCP echo server and client.  If these are tied together, then no traffic should need to go to the host, right?  Is there anything special I would need to do to get this to work?  I don't have a ton of experience with networking.

Since this is technically a baremetal application, CLI options like `-nic user,hostfwd=tcp::5022-:22` give the warning `qemu-system-arm: warning: nic cadence_gem.1 has no peer.`
(Found at [How to replace `qemu-system -redir` command argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041082/how-to-replace-qemu-system-redir-command-argument)).

If I ever did want to send traffic between the host and guest (like having a `ncat` echo server, instead of in FreeRTOS), how would I go about doing that?

Here is a related problem, with no solution:
[Running LWIP TCP/IP Stack with QEMU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893190/running-lwip-tcp-ip-stack-with-qemu)

Current command line arguments:

```
qemu-system-arm -semihosting --semihosting-config enable=on,target=native -nographic -serial mon:stdio -machine xilinx-zynq-a9 -m 512M -cpu cortex-a9 -nic user,hostfwd=tcp::12346-:7 -kernel build/rtos_demo_tcp/rtos_demo_tcp.elf
```

Current output (I enabled extra debug messages):

```
qemu-system-arm: warning: nic cadence_gem.1 has no peer
Seed for randomiser: 1591112953
Random numbers: 00001294 00001925 000022D0 00005CC3
FreeRTOS_IPInit
vTaskStartScheduler
prvIPTask started
Network buffers: 30 lowest 30


IP Address: 10.2.118.223
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway Address: 10.2.118.1
DNS Server Address: 208.67.222.222


Socket 7 -> 0ip:0 State eCLOSED->eTCP_LISTEN
```

Then this next bit repeats indefinitely, with a different socket number each time:

```
FreeRTOS_connect: 14207 to a0276dfip:7
Socket 14207 -> a0276dfip:7 State eCLOSED->eCONNECT_SYN
ARP for a0276dfip (using a0276dfip): rc=0 00:00:00 00:00:00
Network buffers: 30 lowest 29
Connect[a0276dfip:7]: next timeout 1: 500 ms
ARP for a0276dfip (using a0276dfip): rc=0 00:00:00 00:00:00
Connect[a0276dfip:7]: next timeout 2: 500 ms
ARP for a0276dfip (using a0276dfip): rc=0 00:00:00 00:00:00
Connect[a0276dfip:7]: next timeout 3: 500 ms
Connect: giving up a0276dfip:7
Socket 14207 -> a0276dfip:7 State eCONNECT_SYN->eCLOSE_WAIT
FreeRTOS_closesocket[14207 to a0276dfip:7]: buffers 30 socks 1
```

**Summary:** How do I change the way I am calling QEMU so that the TCP client and server can connect to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend trying out all of the options enumerated in the [qemu networking guide](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking):
- [SLIRP](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#User_Networking_.28SLIRP.29): `-netdev user,id=mynet0,net=192.168.76.0/24,dhcpstart=192.168.76.9`
- [TAP](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#Tap): `-netdev tap,id=mynet0`
- [SOCKET](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#Socket): `-netdev socket,id=mynet0,listen=:1234` and `-netdev socket,id=mynet0,connect=:1234`

And there is much more in the guide. Something you might also consider is that it might be difficult for you to port-forward directly from the VM you care about to the host, and it might be easier to connect that VM to *another VM* and port-forward from that second VM to your host.

Sounds a bit odd, but that's something I've needed to do before. To talk between two VM's I find [sockets](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#Socket) to be the best method. They work sort of like a "virtual crossover cable".

This VM to VM method would allow you to simply have to set up corresponding static IP's and subnets on each VM and then `ncat`'s would work between them. Do away with all of the complexity of a DHCP server and any sort of port-forwarding.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I made 2 versions of the code, one running the server task, and another the client task. I've changed the network part of the qemu call to be:
`-nic socket,id=n1,mac=00:17:34:51:68:65,listen=:2222` and
`-nic socket,id=n2,mac=00:17:34:51:68:66,connect=127.0.0.1:2222`, respectively.
Now the client task makes more progress than it did, but the server still won't connect.
I'll keep hacking on it, but any other suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Keep at it. When developing with QEMU there are always the  "Did I do something wrong with my QEMU command?" and "Am I doing something wrong in my VM?". The best approach is to nail down and be confident in how to virtualize your environment **first**. I believe you've got your QEMU command right. Now It's time to ask a networking question.